# Swift to Arduino using serial

Tags: swift, macos, arduino, serial-port, orsserialport

For my school project, i want to create a MacOS application that communicates with my Arduino using a serial connection. I tried 2 different library (SwiftSerial and ORSSerialPort). Both without succes. Probably because I'm a beginner with Swift.

I decided to continue with `ORSSerialPort` because I can find more information about this library. Not a loth but more then SwiftSerial.

So the problem: If I create the `ORSSerialPort` object, it think that my parameters don't come through the constructor (init()). Because when i try to read the variables in the object I get a nil. Even when I do this: 
`port?.baudRate = 9600`
baudRate stays nil.

Here my code:

**ViewController.swift**

```
import Cocoa

var port: SerialParser?

class ViewController: NSViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        port = SerialParser(path: "/dev/cu.usbmodem14101")

    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


    @IBAction func ledOn(_ sender: Any) {
        port?.open()
        port?.sendString(data: "1")
        port?.close()
    }


    @IBAction func ledOff(_ sender: Any) {
        port?.open()
        port?.sendString(data: "0")
        port?.close()
    }
}
```

**SerialParser.swift**

```
import Cocoa
import ORSSerial

class SerialParser : NSObject, ORSSerialPortDelegate {
    var port : ORSSerialPort?

    init(path: String){
        port = ORSSerialPort(path: path)
        print("path: \(port?.path)")
    }

    func open(){
        port?.baudRate = 9600
        port?.delegate = self
        if let portUnwraped = port {
            portUnwraped.open()
            print("path: \(portUnwraped.path) baudRate: \(portUnwraped.baudRate)")
        }else{
            print("port object empty");
        }
    }

    func close(){
        port?.delegate=nil
        port?.close()
        print("poort closed")
    }

    func sendString(data: String){
        let dataa = Data(data.utf8)
        port?.send(dataa)
        print("Data sended: \(data)")
    }

    func serialPortWasRemovedFromSystem(_ serialPort: ORSSerialPort) {
        print("PORT REMOVED")
    }

}
```

**My output**

```
path: nil
port object empty
Data sended: 1
poort closed
``
```

Comment: Are you sure the path `/dev/cu.usbmodem14101` is correct/valid? What kind of Arduino are you using?

Comment: @Andrew Madsen Yes the path should be correct, if I type ``ls -l /dev/cu.*``` in Terminal my Arduino shows up as ```/dev/cu.usbmodem14101```. I use Arduino Uno

Comment: communicating to the USB port on the uno?

Comment: @RichardBarber, Yes!

Comment: My unos usually show up as /dev/ttyACM0 and use 115200 baud.

Comment: I am sure this is the correct path. I tried to make a serial connection with the same path using Xojo. And it works flawless. But I don't like Xojo and I want It to work in swift

Comment: Have you tried Swift for Arduino? Perhaps is an alternative you should consider, but I actually don’t know if it works with serial ports.

Comment: @jvarela I looked at it, but I don't have a problem with the Arduino itself. I can retrieve serial data with the Arduino. but I can't send the data with my swift project.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked, the example `OSRSerialPortDemo` example from the ORSSerial library works straight out of the box on my M1 running Monterey. It however detects the USB port as usbmodem1101 or usbmodem1201, unlike the Arduino IDE which is detecting it as usbmodem14101 or the like when the Arduino is attached to the mac via a USB hub rather than directly to a USB port of the mac.
I would suggest you to check you are hooked up directly to the mac, and to use the demo app to check the actual names of the serial port.
As an alternative you may prefer to use the demo app and customize it to your needs.